# Find objects list in Javascript

Tags: javascript, find

I have a list of objects like this:

```
{code:"E21", msg:"Message of code E21", type:"blue"}
{code:"E22", msg:"Message of code E22", type:"red"}
```

And I use `.find()` to return the message of specific code like this:

```
var eventCode = "E20";
var result =  iprsMsgList.find(result => result.code === eventCode);
var resultMsg = result.msg;
```

but if the code is not find it skips the message and get this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msg' of undefined

I need to do some how not to skip and give me a message like.. message not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var resultMsg = typeof result !== 'undefined' ? result.msg : 'message not found';
```

That should do the trick. You need to check if a message was returned and if not return the string error you wanted. The ternary above does that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and check if the object is truthy.

```
var resultMsg = result ? result.msg : 'not found';
```